# Command line with multiple libraries

Tags: java, command

I am trying to run my java class by command line. When I executed throw an error:

```
PS C:\Users\mcruz\Desktop\diff-java> javac src/main/Main.java
src\main\Main.java:8: error: package com.google.gson does not exist
import com.google.gson.Gson;
                      ^
src\main\Main.java:10: error: package object does not exist
import object.Command;
             ^
src\main\Main.java:11: error: package object does not exist
import object.Environments;
             ^
src\main\Main.java:12: error: package object does not exist
import object.MetadataType;
             ^
src\main\Main.java:13: error: package object does not exist
import object.PackageBuild;
             ^
src\main\Main.java:14: error: package object does not exist
import object.ReadFile;
             ^
src\main\Main.java:16: error: package object does not exist
import object.Resource;
```

I don't know if this command detects the libraries that I implement in the project or what I need to do to solve this problem. (My libraries are in a folder with the name lib.)

I read in another post that I can use javac -cp to add the classpath but, I need to add more than one library.

```
Example : 
javac -cp lib/error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar;lib/gson-2.9.0.jar;lib/logger-1.24.0.jar;lib/logger-slf4j-1.24.0.jar;lib/logger-spi-1.24.0.jar;lib7safe-logging-1.24.0.jar;lib/slf4j-api-1.7.31.jar  src/main/Main.java

package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import object.Command;
import object.Environments;
import object.MetadataType;
import object.PackageBuild;
import object.ReadFile;

import object.Resource;

public class Main { ........
```

Comment: Please do not place links to images - place piece of used code, error message(s) and what you tried to do and to fix it...

Comment: So what's the problem with adding more libraries? Just use `;` to seperate them (on Windows; on Linux, it would be `:`) as you showed in the command.

Comment: +1 to @dan1st question: what's the problem with specifying multiple JARs. If you're looking for a way to have shorter build commands, then some build system can be used. Those have a config stored in a separate file and know how to orchestrate the build including downloading dependancies of a specific version. There are different build systems available: Maven, Gradle, CMake, Bazel. Pick whatever is the most common for your current or a future use case (e. g. backend dev, android dev, desktop app dev). Good luck!

Comment: I try to create a command-line adding multiples jars and multiples objects. When I execute this command "javac -d /bin src/main/Main.java" throws the error.

Comment: `javac -d . -cp lib\*.jar  src/main/Main.java` might ddo it for you, but in general, command line compilation without a build tool scales badly